# Copy vtkImageData into another vtkImageData

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, mfc, vtk

I have a **vtkDICOMReader** in a VC++/MFC application, in the main thread. Because retrieving data in this object could take long time, I would like to get data, let say from HDD, into separate thread. In that second thread, I create another **vtkDICOMReader** object. And this **vtkDICOMReader** should be transferred into **vtkDICOMReader** *from the main thread* ... how can I do that ?

Kind of pseudocode:

```
CMyDoc::m_pDICOMReader;
```

in the second thread, I create a local **vtkDICOMReader** with

```
vtkDICOMReader* pReader = vtkDICOMReader::New();
pReader->ReadData(...);  // could take long time
::PostMessage(AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd(), WMU_TRANSFER, 0, (LPARAM)pReader);
```

In the main thread:

```
LRESULT CMyDoc::OnTransfer(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    vtkDICOMReader* pReader = (vtkDICOMReader*)lParam;
    // transfer pReader to m_pDICOMReader somehow ...
    m_pDICOMReader = pReader;    // <-- this is the point where I don't know how to transfer data from pReader to m_pDICOMReader
    pReader->Delete();
}
```

Or, to avoid this transfer, from a separate thread **vtkImageData** to the main thread **vtkImageData**, can I load data directly into **vtkImageData** main thread in such a way that I can cancel reading input data ? If is possible, how can I do that ?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2015 (or later), just go with C++20 coroutines. It's by far the easiest way to move computationally expensive and/or otherwise time consuming operations off of a thread that needs to remain responsive (like a UI thread). No need to manually move objects across threads, or to send notification messages. Just make sure to switch to the UI thread, whenever you need to update UI thread state. [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt) has convenient helpers for thread control.

Comment: @IInspectable What are these "C++ 20 coroutines"?

Comment: I am not familiar with vkt, but it seems your pseudo-code is just passing a pointer and not copying the object. You might want to ask a "vtk only question" about how to copy the vtk object in a single function, you might get better help from vtk experts. On MFC side, you can experiment with passing a character string to another thread, then create a copy of that string. The same principle will apply to vtk objects.

Comment: In a nutshell, they are generalized callbacks. Lewis Baker has a fairly thorough series on the fundamentals ([Coroutine Theory](https://lewissbaker.github.io/2017/09/25/coroutine-theory), [C++ Coroutines: Understanding operator co_await](https://lewissbaker.github.io/2017/11/17/understanding-operator-co-await), and [C++ Coroutines: Understanding the promise type](https://lewissbaker.github.io/2018/09/05/understanding-the-promise-type)). Coroutines can be used primarily for generators and asynchronous code. In the latter case, you can write your async operations as a sequence of steps.

Comment: Essentially, all your asynchronous code is written as a sequence of statements in a single function, where all code can share common state. Switching back and forth between (threadpool) threads is completely transparent. You aren't going to appreciate them until you have used them.

Comment: Yes, in fact is a VTK question, but maybe can avoid retrieving data in another thread somehow, using VTK feature that I didn't know yet. And because whole handling data is written in MFC/VC++, I put this tag too ..